# Why in firestore will a if let statement change the type of a document variable?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I was just hoping for an explanation re: what is happening below.
In the first if let statement where document = document flatmap no longer is a member of DocumentSnapshot whereas in the second if let i'm obviously able to call flatmap on the document in the if let statement. I just don't quite get why that is.

I checked the type and they are both DocumentSnapshots the only difference is one is an optional.

Thx.

```
 var docref:DocumentReference?
 docref = db.collection("users").document(uid)
 docref?.getDocument { (document, error) in

      if let document = document{

       //document.flatmap won't work
       //value of DocumentSnapshot has no member flatmap

      }         

      if let profile = document.flatMap({$0.data()})
      {

         self.model.currentLoggedInUser?.id = profile["id"] as! String

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if let document = document` unwraps the previous `document`, and binds it to a new constant `document`, that shadows the previous `document` within the `{ ... }`.

If `document` had type `T?` before, the new, shadowing `document` has type `T`.

It's similar to regular variable shadowing:

```
let a = 1

if true {
    let a = 2 //shadows the outer `a`
    print(a) // => 2
}
```

In all, this code behaves similar to this:

```
let document: Document? = MaybeReturnADocument()

if document != nil { // Illustrative only, don't do this!
    let document: Document = document! // shadows the outer document of type `Document?`
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx @Alexander. I just did some reading. In your if true statement just to confirm will print(a) print 1? I thought it would print the vale of the variable in the current scope (ie 2)

Comment: @Mike Ooops, it should print 2, that was a typo!